# How to replace character to tab stop?

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

Is there a way to change a character into a tab stop? Here is my input and output:

[image]

In my understanding, a table of content can only be achieved after you have, well, a content. While in here I just purely process data, and I have no content below. There is an option for tab stop in Advanced Find, but it also run for the tabs at the beginning of the lines. Here I just want to have a replace the slash with a right tab stop. All else untouched.

Comment: Are you creating a table of contents?

Comment: What software are you using? Is this a plain text file? Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio yes, but that table, in my understanding, can only be achieved after you have, well, a content. While in here I just purely process data, and I have no content below

Comment: @ToDo Microsoft Word 2016, Windows 7. Yes, this is a plain text I copy from another source

Comment: [Word and Excel - Power User Tips and Tricks](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/PowerUser_MSOffice.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working on Word requires many roundabouts, because Word doesn't support standard regex.

**Step 1:** Remove all existing tabs that may come from the other data source, but at the same time mark the start of the line by a unique symbol. In my case, I replace `^t` with `α`. The number of `α`s indicates the level of the heading.

**Step 2a:** Show all styles

[image]

**Step 2b:** Modify each TOC level style to your preference. Also,
[image]

Repeat when all heading levels are correct.

**Step 3:** Use Advanced Find feature and match each heading level with its style

[image]

The result is nice and rewarding:

[image]